# Case Escalation Action Doesn't Fire Based on Time Criteria?

Tags: escalation

I had created new escalation rules with following criteria

```
(Case: Issue type CONTAINS Regular) AND (Case: Status CONTAINS New)
```

Business Hours Settings - Use business hours specified on case.

How escalation times are set-   Based on when the case is created.

**Case Escalation Actions**

[image]

And I created new case and tried to test. but after 30 minutes I did not get any email, despite what I indicated in escalation action.

I have checked in **Case Escalation**  in **Setup** . I can see my case as listed down in escalated Queue. After age 30 minutes crossed I can still see case in escalated queue list.

And also I checked in `Case` object for a field `IsEscalated` but it is false after 30 minutes.

What am I missing? How can I get the email to send?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Escalation Rules is not able to test in Sandbox because of the salesforce limitation.

Service Exclusions 
The following features are disabled and can’t be enabled in sandboxes.

Case escalation are disabled because they automatically send email to contacts, customers, and production org users.

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=data_sandbox_implementation_tips.htm&type=5

You can however look at the monitoring > case escalations to see whether your criteria is correct or not.  (It will line up in monitoring, but it won't ever fire unless you are in a production environment)